# Filtering out ints on an array

Tags: java, arrays, printing, filter, int

method takes in an array of ints and returns the new array of ints without even ints.  Ive written something up but cannot get the print right in the main method....heres what I have

```
 //filterAway method taking out evens from string

    public static int[] filterArray(int[] x){
            int [] arrayOne;
            int size = 0;

            for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
                if(x[i] % 2 != 0){
                    size++;
                }
            }

            arrayOne = new int [size];

            int index =0;
            for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
                if(x[i] % 2 != 0){
                    arrayOne[index] = x[1];
                    index++;
                }
            }
            return arrayOne;
        }

    //main 

     public static void main(String args[]){
            int[] f = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
            for (int i =0; i <f.length; i++){
                System.out.print(f[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
                                                   //here is where im struggling.
            int [] fA= (filterAway);               // say the string is 1-12....cannot get 
                                                   // filtered array to print
            for (int i =0; i <fA.length; i++){
                System.out.print(arrayOne[i] + " ");
            }``
            System.out.println(" ");
                }
```

Comment: `int[] fA=filterAway(f)` What is the `arrayOne` array, it should be `fA`

Answer (score 1):

### **Fixing the Display Problem**

Try this revised main method, just replace **YourClassName** with your class name:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] f = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(f[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    // here is where im struggling.
    int[] fA = YourClassName.filterArray(f);
    // filtered array to print
    for (int i = 0; i < fA.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(fA[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

However, you'll see you might end up getting something like 2, 2, 2, 2 there. You need to revisit your filterArray function.

### **Fixing the `filterArray` function**

Since the title of your question is Filtering Out Ints in Java, here's the culprit, change **1** to **i**, that's why it gives out 2, 2, 2, 2. Also, you want even numbers, so you should look for 0 modulo, change your comparator to ==, instead of !=.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass your `f[]` as an argument to your `filterAway()` method.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] f = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    for (int i =0; i <f.length; i++){
        System.out.print(f[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    int [] fA= filterArray(f);               
    for (int i =0; i <fA.length; i++){
        System.out.print(fA[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error message. cannot find symbol - method filterAway(int [])

Comment: I now noticed that your filterAway method is static so you won't need the classname-part. Just ìnt [] fA = filterAway(f);

Comment: still getting the same error message...how can I get int [] fA = filterAway(f); in scope?

Comment: In your last printing loop you have System.out.print(arrayOne[i] + " ");
arrayOne doesn't exist in mains scope, so you'll also want to change that to fA[i] + " ";

There's also a slight logical fallacy in your filter-algorithm, but I'll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should do with your requirements:

```
package com.sandbox;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] all = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

        int[] filtered = odds(all);
        for (int i : filtered) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    private static int[] odds(int[] all) {
        int sizeOfResult = 0;
        for (int i : all) {
            if (isOdd(i)) {
                sizeOfResult++;
            }
        }

        int[] result = new int[sizeOfResult];
        int resultIndex = 0;
        for (int i : all) {
            if (isOdd(i)) {
                result[resultIndex] = i;
                resultIndex++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static boolean isOdd(int i) {
        return i % 2 != 0;
    }
}
```

Here's what I'd do if I were writing this on my own though:  I'd use a List instead of an array, and I'd use [`CollectionUtils.filter`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29).  Here's a snippet of code that will do what you want:

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.google.common.primitives.Ints.asList;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
        CollectionUtils.filter(result, new Predicate() {
            @Override
            public boolean evaluate(Object o) {
                return isOdd((Integer) o);
            }
        });
        for (Integer integer : result) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isOdd(int i) {
        return i % 2 != 0;
    }
}
```